# Python, Conditionals - Are these equivalent?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

```
if config == 'H/2' or 'H' or '2H': pass
if config == 'H/2' or config == 'H' or config == '2H': pass
```

Comment: No.  Why do you ask?  Did you try them?

Comment: I tried them, they seemed equivalent. It surprised me. Perhaps my test wasn't thorough enough.

Comment: "I tried them"?  Really?  How?

Comment: No, not the same, but (just guessing) you might find it interesting, that you could write `if config in ('H/2', 'H', '2H'): pass` which is equivalent to your second line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> config = 'H/2'
>>> config == 'H/2' or 'H' or '2H'
True
>>> config == 'H/2' or config == 'H' or config == '2H'
True

>>> config = 'H'
>>> config == 'H/2' or 'H' or '2H'
'H'
>>> config == 'H/2' or config == 'H' or config == '2H'
True

>>> config = 'R'
>>> config == 'H/2' or 'H' or '2H'
'H'
>>> config == 'H/2' or config == 'H' or config == '2H'
False
```

Comment: The last example doesn't make sense to me.  Why does the comparison return 'H'?

Comment: The or operator doesn't necessarily convert to bool.  From help("or"): The expression `x or y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is true, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.  Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they
return to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated
argument. This is sometimes useful, e.g., if `s` is a string that
should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression
`s or 'foo'` yields the desired value.

Comment: The **or** operator doesn't ever convert to bool.  By definition.  The values are left intact.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since `pass` does nothing and presumably `config.__eq__` has no side-effects, I suppose they're equivalent (in that nothing happens).

If you replace `pass` with something else, though, you'll notice that the first conditional always executes and the second depends on the value of `config`.

Perhaps you would like to write

```
if config in ['H/2', 'H', '2H']:
    # do stuff
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Do either:

```
if config in ('H/2', 'H', '2H'): # more efficient than a list
    do_something()
```

or (if you are doing this often or the possible set of values is much larger):

```
# once
config_h_set = set(('H/2', 'H', '2H'))

# later
if config in config_h_set:
    do_something()
```